# Adding multiple parameters to ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, enumerated-types

I'm having trouble figuring out this assignment. I am only seeking an answer for a specific problem, as it seems I am a bit lost when adding things to an Array List. I have a 'Gym' class with the add method, which is supposed to create a 'Member' object from the Member class.

```
public class Gym {

    private String gymName;              // Identifies the name of the gym.
    private ArrayList<Member> members;   // A list of member objects.
    private double[] gymRates;           // A map that relates membership type to its fee.
    private double trainerRate;          // indicates rate charge for one hour with PT.

    /**
     * Add a new member to a gym's list of members.
     * 
     * @param hoursQ1    number of personal trainer hours the member had for quarter one.
     * @param hoursQ2    number of personal trainer hours the member had for quarter two.
     * @param hoursQ3    number of personal trainer hours the member had for quarter three.
     * @param hoursQ4    number of personal trainer hours the member had for quarter four.
     */
    public void addMember(String firstName, String lastName, MembershipType memberType, int hoursQ1, int hoursQ2,
            int hoursQ3, int hoursQ4) {
        members.add(new Member(firstName, lastName, memberType, hoursQ1, hoursQ2, hoursQ3, hoursQ4));
    }

    /**
     * Add a specified member to a gym's list of members.
     * 
     * @param member     the member to add.
     */
    public void addMember(Member member) {
        Member.add(member);
    }
}

public class Member {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private MembershipType memberType;
    private int[] trainerHours = new int[4];
}
```

From my understanding the error (arguments differ in length), is because the parameter has the hours Q1-Q4, and I'm not correctly initializing those into the trainerHours array?

Also, my trainerHours array is supposed to use an enumerated type class 'Quarter' as the indices, Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4. I haven't figured this out either..
Sorry for formatting, having trouble with that too here! ;)

Comment: Have you defined a constructor for Member, that takes all of those parameters?

Comment: `Member.add(member);` this must be `members.add(member);` in `public void addMember(Member member)` method.

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson Nope, and thats exactly what I expected. I got one error saying something about a constructor of the Member class. I think the project description confused me a bit as it somewhat implied that I only need those private fields in Member, it has no such constructor. I suppose it wanted me to figure that out? Anyway let me try making one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 problems in your code :

- first, when you call new Member (...), that function is not defined, because you haven't defined a constructor with these arguments for the class Member
- second, your second addMember method is wrong, it should be members.add(...) instead of Member.add

Comment: Thank you for pointing those out, as people have said already but it's nice to see some clarification, and it makes sense. The reason I had Member.add was I thought I was creating a new object of the Member class.

Answer (score 0):

I should make the following constructor for Member class:

```
public Member(String pFirstName, String pLastName, MembershipType pMemberType, int hoursQ1, int hoursQ2, int hoursQ3, int hoursQ4){
    firstName = pFirstName;
    lastNam = pLastName;
    memberType = pMemberType;
    trainerHours[0] = hoursQ1;
    trainerHours[1] = hoursQ2;
    trainerHours[2] = hoursQ3;
    trainerHours[3] = hoursQ4;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that! This is exactly what I thought I needed, however there is still the problem of using enumerated types. I have enum class Quarter with constants Q1 Q2 Q3 and Q4. So I need trainerHours[Q1]. Which I assumed would be trainerHours[Quarter.Q1] but that doesn't work.